# Where & How is user group information stored in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, etcpasswd

Mirror Question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217300/where-how-is-user-group-information-stored-in-ubuntu. (I'll remove one of them after I got the answer)

---

Two places possible: [/etc/group](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcgroup-file/) and [/etc/passwd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/passwd.5.html).

If I use command: `adduser [username] [groupname]`, then the user would be added to the group, and the file `/etc/group` would then be updated.

However, the file `/etc/passwd` is not updated. if I check which group I belongs to, via `groups` command, I can only see groups stated in `passwd` file.. therefore, the user is not added to the group base on this result.

---

I'm confused.

1. What's the meaning of storying group info into `/etc/passwd`, and `/etc/group` respectively?
2. Why `adduser` only update the `group` file?
3. How to add group to the `passwd` file via command?
4. Why does `groups` return group info from `passwd` file, but not `group` file?

Thanks.

Comment: I feel like this question  might be more suited for [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing out. I'll ask one there correspondingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In these traditional text files (there are other ways, e.g. LDAP), your *primary* group goes to `/etc/passwd` (it's e.g. used for permissions of files you create), all additional groups go to `/etc/group`.
2. see 1.
3. That's impossible, but you can *change* a *primary group* with `usermod -g`
4. That's a misinterpretation, `groups` shows **all** groups. But a new group is only picked up when you start a new session (new login). You can use the `newgrp` command, that starts a session with the given group name as your *primary group* (you must be member of this group) -- as a side effect, it will consult the user database and update your groups list.

Comment: Thanks, that's really complete answer. One more question: what's the difference between `primary group`, and `normal group`?

Comment: A running process has *one* group id ... when you start a process, it has your user id and the group id of your primary group. That's why files you create normally have the group id of your primary group. `newgrp` starts a sub-session with a different primary group, I guess by calling `setsid(2)` and `setgid(2)` and then `execv(3)` your shell

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks!